# Intercambiar datos de dos registros con struct en c

Tags: c, bucle-for, struct

Tengo un grupo de datos metidos en un struct, y quiero cambiar de lugar, por ejemplo, el primer registro con el tercero, he intentado hacerlo con el metodo de la burbuja pero nada.

```
//Mostrar les dades segons format demanat
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
printf("\n\n %d)  %s %s %s té %d anys i medeix %.2f.m\n",i+1,colla[i].nom,colla[i].cog1,colla[i].cog2,colla[i].edat,colla[i].alcada);
}

printf("Introdueix una posició del vector");
scanf("%d",&pos);
printf("Introdueix un altre posició del vector");
scanf("%d",&pos2);

for(i=0;i<5;i++);


for(i=0;i<5;i++){
printf("\n\n %d)  %s %s %s té %d anys i medeix %.2f.m\n",i+1,colla[i].nom,colla[i].cog1,colla[i].cog2,colla[i].edat,colla[i].alcada);
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: El algoritmo de la burbuja sirve para ordenar registros en base a un criterio, no para intercambiar dos elementos de posición

Answer (score 0):

Las estructuras son copiables directamente. Para intercambir dos estructuras entre sí tienes que usar una tercera temporal:

```
struct X temp = colla[0];
colla[0] = colla[2];
colla[2] = temp;
```

Donde yo pongo `struct X` tu pon el nombre de tu estructura. Para futuras preguntas estaría bien que añadieses la declaración de las estructuras